# Using cryptDB with TPC-H benchmark

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if anyone had the chance to run cryptDB over a dataset generated by the TPC-H benchmark? 
I've generated a database of size 1GB and loaded the tables into MySQl server (I named the database **TPCH_TEST**). I then run a cryptDB proxy in front of the same MySQL server. Each time I try to run a query against **TPCH_TEST**, I encounter the following error message:

```
ERROR 1105 (07000): Error: Bad Query: [select * from CUSTOMER limit 5]
Error Data: open_normal_and_derived_tables
FILE: main/rewrite_main.cc
LINE: 1380
```

I then though about loading the tables generated by TPCH into a database **while I'm being connected to the cryptDB proxy** (instead of loading the tables, then running the cryptDB proxy). But each time I run the following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'region.tbl' INTO TABLE REGION FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

I get this error message:

```
ERROR 1105 (07000): unhandled sql command 30
```

Any idea how this could be solved? or if there's any other benchmark that actually works with a cryptDB proxy

**NOTE**:
CryptDB is working properly. I generated a small database with one table and tried to run some queries on it and everything worked perfectly. I only run into issues when I try running queries over the tpch generated data.

Thanks,